# Automatically Uppercase Textfield With International Keyboard Support

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to uppercase all characters input into a UITextField with the following so far (working great for US keyboard):

```
self.textField = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
...
// delegate
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSRange lowercaseCharRange = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet]];

    if (lowercaseCharRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                 withString:[string uppercaseString]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The issue occurs when using an international keyboard such as Chinese (Pinying) because the way the characters behave (queued in lowercase). Is there a solution for this/way to check for keyboard internalization type?

Comment: Pinyin shouldn't be uppercase AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a lot simpler to skip the check and just always replace the text with the uppercase version.  **Note that I also used the current locale so that it will consider their locale when converting to uppercase**:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                             withString:[string uppercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
    return NO;
}
```

Performance shouldn't be an issue in this case, and you don't need the original search.

Comment: Still not working. I think the issue is that pinying appends _lowercase_ letters to the end of textfield, and that this is replacing it with the uppercase version, so the Pinying support is removed. There needs to be a way to separate the display of the text with the actual replacement gracefully. (ultimately my goal is to display uppercase letters, while still giving the user the ability to insert pinying characters)

Comment: You tried this with `[string uppercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]` per my example?  If that doesn't work, then it is a bug that should be reported to Apple....

Comment: True, have you tried the code successfully on iOS6? I tried it without the code (leaving all lowercase, and everything worked fine, but with the locale, support is broken)

Comment: No, I haven't tried it (I'm not familiar with Pinyin so am not sure how to test it) but using uppercaseStringWithLocale: should be smart enough to know that it can't capitalize Pinyin if it will change the meaning....

Comment: Ah I see...you can enable PinYin...all you have to do is Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard